# Marketing cloud not allowing the use of SELECT * when there is a join in the query

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, automationstudio

As the title suggests, if I try and write a query like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TableA
LEFT JOIN TableB
ON TableA.Field = TableB.Field
```

I get an error saying

> An error occurred while checking the query syntax. Errors: 'SELECT * ' is not allowed if you use JOINs. Please specify all the column names you want to select

I know this can be done in SQL. Is this a marketing cloud limitation? Is there another way around this without having to type out every column in the query?

Comment: You can drag and drop the source data extension from the list on the left, it will then populate all the available fields into the query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are NOT allowed to use * while using joins in SFMC SQL activity.

And to answer your second question, YES there is a easy way of doing this.

> You can just DRAG n DROP the DataExtension in the place of *

Please find the below illustration video link below.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxsoI.gif

[image]

Comment: that. also, you want to avoid it. As it will only respect fields present at time of its creation, and will "lose track" of changes to the DE made later, making maintenance no fun.

Comment: @JonasLamberty agreed! Thanks for sharing your inputs.

Comment: Thanks for the drag and drop method. @Jonas I have also run into the issue of  SELECT * "losing track" of new fields. However, I think that simply editing the query and resaving it (so it validates again) fixes the problem.